# jQuery inArray in not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var formFields = [
                        {value:"123",category:[1,2]}
                        ];
            formFields.map(function(ele){
                console.log(ele.category);
                if( $.inArray(3,ele.category)){
                    console.log("hai");
                }else{
                    console.log("nahi hai");
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: `3` is not in array so output should be `nahi hai` not `hai`

Comment: Try this  if ($.inArray(3, ele.category) != -1) {